# Testing component using fromEvent click on document with Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, jestjs

I have a component using `fromEvent` to add a click listener to the whole document:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class MyComponent {
  onClick = fromEvent(this._windowRef.nativeWindow.document, 'click')
    .pipe(
      skip(1),
      filter((event: MouseEvent) => this._doStuff()),
    )
    .subscribe(() => {
      // do stuff
    });
}
```

But in the test, I got an error when instancing the component:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined
```

At the pipe after the `fromEvent`

This is what my test look like:

```
const fromEventMock = jest.spyOn(rxjs, 'fromEvent').mockReturnValue(of({ data: 123 }));

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [SomeModule],
      declarations: [
        MyComponent,
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: WindowRef,
          useValue: {
            nativeWindow: {
              document: {
                addEventListener: jest.fn(),
                removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
              },
            },
          },
        },
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The mock of `fromEvent` is working as expected. I tried multiple mock strategy but the problem seems to occur before that.

I tried mocking the `WindowRef`, not mocking it. Same thing for `fromEvent`.

Does anyone had that problem before? What am I missing here?